# Apex:InputText - Handle Apostrophes

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, inputtext

How do I handle apostrophes when using apex:inputtext component to set the value of a search?

Some searches indicate `string.escapeSingleQuotes(searchString);` or `{!JSENCODE(!searchString)}` would resolve but I am confused on appropriate usage.

**Example of Component:**

```
<apex:page controller="myClass" showHeader="true">
    <apex:inputText id="searchString" value="{!searchString}" onkeypress="return noenter(event);"/>
</apex:page>
```

**Example of Controller:**

```
public class myClass {
    Public string searchString{get;set;}
}
```

**Error Received:**

EX: Searching O'Doole = unexpected token: 'Doole'

This variable is used to set another variable in myClass:

```
if(searchType == 'lastNameSearch') {
    searchWhere = 'client_Last_Name  = \'' + searchString + '\'';
    searchLastName = true;
    }
```

Comment: This scenario is covered quite clearly [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use variable binding, you don't do anything special at all; the system does it for you.

```
<apex:page controller="myClass" showHeader="true">
    <apex:inputText id="searchString" value="{!searchString}" onkeypress="return noenter(event);"/>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class myClass {
    Public string searchString{get;set;}
    public void doSearch() {
        List<List<SObject>> results = [FIND :searchString RETURNING Account, Contact];
    }
}
```

---

When using Dynamic SOQL/SOSL, use String.escapeSingleQuotes *or* bind to the parameter using a colon. I prefer the latter, because it's easier to read.

---

## Binding

```
if(searchType == 'lastNameSearch') {
  searchWhere = 'Client_Last_Name__c = :searchString';
  searchLastName = true;
}
```

## Escaping

```
if(searchType == 'lastNameSearch') {
  searchWhere = 'Client_Last_Name__c = \''+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchString)+'\'';
  searchLastName = true;
}
```